# Twitter notifications not working on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, notifications, twitter

I am having trouble receiving Twitter notifications on my Mac. I have the account turned on in settings (with notifications turned on) and have checked that access is given to OS X integration in Twitter settings in the browser. Do not disturb is also not turned on. I have tried removing the account and signing in again a few times, notifications work on iOS devices just not the Mac.